# In AVAudioplayer path is not updated in background in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

From background to foreground new audio path is updating but the new audio is not playing in AVAudioplayer, the old audio is playing. Any solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: please share more details of implementation and details of what you have tried to solve so far.

Comment: Thanks I have checked the background mode in capabilities and added the session for background mode and working but when going to background then come to foreground the player is updating the url path but its not playing new one